# How to call templates outside app folder?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

How can I call the `header.html`? This is my folder structure. I am having a `TemplateSyntaxError at /`.

```
- Project Name
    - app
      - home
         - templates      //will contain all the views
             - home.html
         - views..py
      - templates         //will contain all the scripts,styles
         - header.html
```

Here is my code: `Home/templates/home.html`

```
{% extends 'header.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <body>
    </body>
{% endblock content %}
```

**UPDATE**: Here is my Settings.py:

```
APP_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'apps')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            APP_ROOT + '/home/templates',
            APP_ROOT + '/templates',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you show your TEMPLATES setting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman done.

Comment: Just `{% extends 'header.html' %}` would work fine given the layout you have.

Comment: `DIRS` should be a directory, so `APP_ROOT + 'home/templates'` (not dotted)

Comment: I'm gettings an "TemplateDoesNotExist at / header.html". I didnt startapp the template folder. I that right or not?

Comment: Does `APP_ROOT` end with a `/`? otherwise it should be `APP_ROOT + '/templates'`

Comment: @dirkgroten yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
APP_ROOT = projectDirectory/apps
```

I changed the

```
APP_ROOT + '/templates' // projectDirectory/apps/templates
```

to

```
'projectName/apps/templates' //projectName/apps/templates
```

I don't know why it works. I need an explanation.

Comment: You didn't show us the real folder structure and aren't showing us the real code, so it's difficult to help. Why I'm saying that? Because the names you're showing don't actually match ("app", "apps", "projectDirectory", "projectName", "Project Name") so your solution cannot work for your question. If you don't copy&paste your actual code and folder structure here, it's impossible to find the mistake. Every character counts.

Answer (score 0):

According the directory tree of your project you don't need any further configuration. Just replace

```
{% extends '../../templates/header.html' %}
```

By

```
{% extends 'header.html' %}
```

And change

```
APP_ROOT + 'home.templates',
```

By

```
APP_ROOT + 'home/templates',
```

Comment: What's the content of header template?

Comment: the head, header, and footer tag